# WPF Thread with Join() blocks UI thread

Tags: wpf, multithreading, listbox, thread-safety

My main class:

```
List<string> myList;
...
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        myList = myClass.getListData(); // This takes for awhile.
    });
    thread.start();
    thread.join(); // So I want my program to wait the thread is done here.

    listBox1.ItemsSource = myList; // Then, update the listbox.
}
```

I know thread.Join() causes blocking my UI thread.

How do I prevent?

I could do this with BackgroundWorker, but I want to know how keep using Thread.

PLUS)

In threading part, I can separate task like this:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() => {
    myClass.doSomething(); // Adding data into a list in the other class.
    myList = myClass.getList(); // Get the list from the other class.
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your thread call back to the UI to set the ItemsSource:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        myList = myClass.getListData();
        Action uiAction = () => listBox1.ItemsSource = myList;
        Dispatcher.Invoke(uiAction); // Execute on the UI thread
    });
    thread.Start();
}
```

If possible, use asynchrony in C# 5 though - that would be much cleaner:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myList = await myClass.GetListDataAsync();
    listBox1.ItemsSource = myList;
}
```

Comment: Wow it is very quick response! thanks. and can you give me example code (or link) for the second example? It gives error saying 'Cannot await 'System.Collections.Generic.List<..>'.

Comment: @KimchiMan: What do you mean? You'd have to implement `GetListDataAsync` yourself... you haven't told us anything about what it's doing. Asynchrony isn't something you can just "do" with a snap of your fingers - you need to think about it carefully. But if you're trying to make a responsive UI interacting with long-running processes, it's a good thing to look at.

Comment: I found very useful link. Thank you! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx

Comment: and `Invoke(uiAction);` should be `Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(uiAction);`

Comment: @KimchiMan: Edited to use `Dispatcher.Invoke` - there's no need to go through Application.Current, assuming this code is in a UI class.